# Linux Shell Script which logs changes in ongoing process

Tags: unix

Linux Shell Script which logs **changes** in ongoing process. I dont have any idea!

Comment: How about an example?

Comment: Suppose right now 4 process are running and after some time if no of ongoing process are 7 then log should print 3 process that are new

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
while true                      # loop foreva
do 
  mv -i new old                 # mv previous process list as old
  ps -ef > new                  # create new process list
  diff <(sort new) <(sort old)  # see the difference between old and new
  sleep 5                       # sleep for a while (no pun)
done
```

After the first iteration you'd get something like this:

```
174c174
< james    30451  7192  0 15:19 pts/4    00:00:00 ps -ef
---
> james    30443  7192  0 15:19 pts/4    00:00:00 ps -ef
```

(Once you understand what it does, replace `mv -i new old` `mv -f new old`.)

Comment: Thanks you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
#!/bin/bash
exec >> "mylog.log" 2>&1
echo "Some text goes here"
```

**exec** command will redirect all output to file **mylog.log** file 
**echo** command will be printed into **mylog.log** file, not terminal

Comment: But How can i monitor only changes in ongoing process ?